# Nginx changing path

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi

I have been searching thoruhg nginx documentation and posts online but I can't find the answer to this.

I am running a python application and I want one of the paths altered slightly. I can't do this in python for various reasons.

I want the input url:
/public/web/apidocs***
(where *** could be anything - including nothing)
to be passed to the python app as
/apidocs***

This is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost; ##ignored if there is only one server block
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location = /frontend/webfrontendConnectionData {
        try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    }
    location /public/web/frontend {
        alias /frontend/;
        autoindex off;
    }
    location /public/web/adminfrontend {
        alias /adminfrontend/;
        autoindex off;
    }
    location ^(/public/web)(/apidocs.*)$ { 
        try_files $2 @yourapplication;
    }
    location / { 
        try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/app/uwsgi.sock;
    }    
}
```

## Update based on answer so far:

Thank you for pointing out the mistake or missing out the ~ in the config.
The config has changed as follows:

```
location ~ ^(/public/web)(/apidocs.*)$ { 
    try_files $2 @yourapplication;
}
location / { 
    try_files $uri @yourapplication;
}
location @yourapplication {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/app/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

Unfortunately it still doesn't work as expected:

- wget 127.0.0.1:80/apidocs  -> Goes to python App and works as    expected
- wget 127.0.0.1:80/apidocs/  -> Goes to python App and works    as expected
- wget 127.0.0.1:80/apidocs/swagger.json  -> Goes to python    App and works as expected
- wget 127.0.0.1:80/public/web/apidocs ->    FAILS I want this to give the same response as wget 127.0.0.1:80/apidocs
- wget 127.0.0.1:80/public/web/apidocs/ -> FAILS I want this to give the same response as wget 127.0.0.1:80/apidocs/
- wget 127.0.0.1:80/public/web/apidocs/swagger.json -> FAILS I want    this to give the same response as wget 127.0.0.1:80/apidocs/swagger.json

All the failed responses give me:

```
robert@ansiblerunner:~/t$ wget 127.0.0.1:80/public/web/apidocs/swagger.json
--2019-04-08 09:50:39--  http://127.0.0.1/public/web/apidocs/swagger.json
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 NOT FOUND
2019-04-08 09:50:39 ERROR 404: NOT FOUND.
```

Can anyone suggest the correct syntax for the rule I want.

## **Update #2**

After reading more nginx documentation I found out that it doesn't take the location rules in order and use the first one it hits, rather it has a complex longest match algorithm. I was worried the "location /" block was then overriding all the paths so I have altered the config so it is like the following:

```
location /api/public { 
    try_files $uri @yourapplication;
}
location /api/authed { 
    try_files $uri @yourapplication;
}
location ~* ^(/public/web)(/apidocs.*)$ { 
    try_files $2 @yourapplication;
}
#location / { 
#    try_files $uri @yourapplication;
#}
location @yourapplication {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/app/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

/api/public and /api/authed both work as normal.
it's the /public/web/apidocs that doesn't. The difference is that I need nginx to change the path provided to the python app in this case. This is why I have a regexp with two parts and it passing $2 rather than $uri. I don't think it's doing what I expect which is to pass /apidoc to the app.

Comment: The frontend and adminfrond lines work as expected but the appidocs redirect is not. I want /public/web/appidocs to be forwarded to the python app with the URL /appidocs. These redirects may have other strings on the end which also must be forwarded. When I tried I just got not found. I think there is something wrong with either the regex or the $2

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a regex, there, as it lacks a tilde.
You probably want a clause that starts with:

```
location ~ ^(/public/web)(/apidocs.*)$ {
```

You didn't mention which [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) you were reading.
Consulting [a tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms),
Understanding Nginx Server and Location Block Selection Algorithms,
we see the syntax is:

```
location optional_modifier location_match {
```

and we optionally can specify:

> ~: If a tilde modifier is present, this location will be interpreted as a case-sensitive regular expression match.

I cannot explain your reported 404 symptom,
as the `location /` prefix clause should have absorbed the GET request
and at least given @yourapplication an opportunity to **log** the raw URL.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the ~ and it still dosen't work. (I have edited the question.) I think the 404 responses are coming from the application since the application will give 404 if I request /public/web/***. That's why I need to map /public/web/apidocs to /apidocs before passing it to the application.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer
I was completely off base with my understanding of what try_files did not work as I expected. I found an article saying if I use it with an underscore it won't try files and will just use it's fallback.
I also found out that I needed to use rewrite to change the path.
Getting rid of the root location may have not been needed but I prefer not to have it in any case.
My final config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost; ##ignored if there is only one server block
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    #location = /frontend/webfrontendConnectionData {
    #    try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    #}
    location /public/web/frontend {
        alias /frontend/;
        autoindex off;
    }
    location /public/web/adminfrontend {
        alias /adminfrontend/;
        autoindex off;
    }
    # try_files _ @xxx means don't look at any file go to xxx block
    location /api/public { 
        try_files _ @yourapplication;
    }
    location /api/authed { 
        try_files _ @yourapplication;
    }
    location /public/web/apidocs { 
        rewrite ^/public/web(/apidocs.*)$ /$1? break;
        try_files _ @yourapplication;
    }
    #location / { 
    #    try_files _ @yourapplication;
    #}
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/app/uwsgi.sock;
    }    
}
```

Thanks to J_H for comments and answers.